# Android Studio installation rule?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, windows64

I have just downloaded the last build (v0.8.14)

I got a .RAR file. Extracted it and got a folder with some other files.

I'm on W7 64bit so i can't run the "studio.exe" file, i had to run "studio64.exe".

But the IDE just starts itself... No errors, nothing, it just starts, it does not install... I mean, I'm not sent to a wizard process or something...

Does this has anything to do with the new politics that the SDK cannot be inside the installation path anymore and stuff?

Also, is this normal? (because of any other new politics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.8.14 is not the newest one. In Canary Channel is already 1.0 RC2, and if you really like installers it is also there:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-0rc2

Comment: I couldn't find a link to this Canary Channel on Android Developers  dot com. Thank you!